# C++ variadic macro: split argurments at a special separator argument

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have a variadic macro `M` that takes a number of parameters separated by a special argument `SEPARATOR`:

```
M(a, b, c, SEPARATOR, 1, 2, 3);
```

I’d like to have two macros `BEFORE` and `AFTER` that I can call with all of `M`’s arguments and that will return me only the parameters on the left / right side of `SEPARATOR` respectively.

This means `BEFORE(a, b, c, SEPARATOR, 1, 2, 3)` should evaluate to `a, b, c`, whereas `AFTER(a, b, c, SEPARATOR, 1, 2, 3)` should evaluate to `1, 2, 3`.

Based on http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic, I’ve come up with a solution that works for the examples I’ve given above:

```cpp
#define FIRST(a, ...) a
#define SECOND(a, b, ...) b

#define EMPTY()

#define EVAL(...) EVAL1024(__VA_ARGS__)
#define EVAL1024(...) EVAL512(EVAL512(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL512(...) EVAL256(EVAL256(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL256(...) EVAL128(EVAL128(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL128(...) EVAL64(EVAL64(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL64(...) EVAL32(EVAL32(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL32(...) EVAL16(EVAL16(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL16(...) EVAL8(EVAL8(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL8(...) EVAL4(EVAL4(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL4(...) EVAL2(EVAL2(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL2(...) EVAL1(EVAL1(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL1(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define DEFER2(m) m EMPTY EMPTY()()
#define DEFER3(m) m EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY()()()

#define IS_PROBE(...) SECOND(__VA_ARGS__, 0)
#define PROBE() ~, 1

#define CAT(a,b) a ## b

#define NOT(x) IS_PROBE(CAT(_NOT_, x))
#define _NOT_0 PROBE()

#define BOOL(x) NOT(NOT(x))

#define IF_ELSE(condition) _IF_ELSE(BOOL(condition))
#define _IF_ELSE(condition) CAT(_IF_, condition)

#define _IF_1(...) __VA_ARGS__ _IF_1_ELSE
#define _IF_0(...)             _IF_0_ELSE

#define _IF_1_ELSE(...)
#define _IF_0_ELSE(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define HAS_ARGS(...) BOOL(FIRST(_END_OF_ARGUMENTS_ __VA_ARGS__)())
#define _END_OF_ARGUMENTS_() 0

#define IS_SEPARATOR(x) IS_PROBE(CAT(_PROBE_, x))
#define _PROBE_SEPARATOR PROBE()

#define BEFORE_IMPL3(first, ...) IF_ELSE(IS_SEPARATOR(first))(/* do nothing */)(, first DEFER3(_BEFORE_IMPL2)()(__VA_ARGS__))
#define BEFORE_IMPL2(first, ...) IF_ELSE(HAS_ARGS(first))(BEFORE_IMPL3(first, __VA_ARGS__))()
#define _BEFORE_IMPL2() BEFORE_IMPL2
#define BEFORE_IMPL1(first, ...) IF_ELSE(IS_SEPARATOR(first))( /* do nothing */ )(first EVAL(BEFORE_IMPL2(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define BEFORE(first, ...)  IF_ELSE(HAS_ARGS(first))(BEFORE_IMPL1(first, __VA_ARGS__))()

#define AFTER_IMPL2(first, ...) IF_ELSE(IS_SEPARATOR(first))(__VA_ARGS__)(DEFER3(_AFTER_IMPL)()(__VA_ARGS__))
#define AFTER_IMPL(first, ...) IF_ELSE(HAS_ARGS(first))(AFTER_IMPL2(first, __VA_ARGS__))( /* do nothing */ )
#define _AFTER_IMPL() AFTER_IMPL
#define AFTER(...) EVAL(AFTER_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__))
```

There is one problem with this solution, however: It breaks if one of the macro arguments starts with a preprocessor token like `[`, e.g. in `M([[maybe_unused]] int a, foo(), SEPARATOR, "abc")`.

The reason for this is the following: the macro `IS_SEPARATOR` doesn’t work if its argument starts with a token like `[` because it tries to concatenate that token with `_PROBE_`, (in `IS_SEPARATOR([[maybe_unused]] int a)`). This is not allowed and generates the following error:

```
error: pasting "_PROBE_" and "[" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

Do you have any idea how I could fix `IS_SEPARATOR` to work in this situation? Or alternatively another solution how I could implement the `BEFORE` and `AFTER` macros?

**Edit:**
To reproduce the error, you can put all of the above in a file `macros.cpp` plus add the following lines with a dummy implementation of `M` (this will not evaluate to a valid program and my actual implementation is more complex, but this doesn’t matter here as my goal is to fix the preprocessor step for now):

```
#define M(...) BEFORE(__VA_ARGS__) && AFTER(__VA_ARGS__)
M([[maybe_unused]] int a, foo(), SEPARATOR, "abc")
```

Then run the preprocessor with:

```
g++ -E -P macros.cpp -std=c++17
```

The output I’d like to see for this is:

```
[[maybe_unused]] int a , foo() && "abc"
```

Instead, we get the above-mentioned error.

Comment: Looking at your existing macros ... it would be an order of magnitude easier to just write a sed script to do it. Are you wedded to doing this with just the preprocessor?

Comment: @Useless Yes, maybe that could be simpler with something like sed. Unfortunately, this is not an option for me. I might be able to replace `SEPARATOR` with something else, though. Maybe an empty argurment, or a pair of parentheses `()`. I might be able to detect these wtihout token pasting, so I’ll probably look into that now.

Comment: Why not just write `M((a, b, c), (1, 2, 3));`? Why not just write BEFORE(a, b, c) && AFTER(1, 2, 3)` for that matter? What is the point of having a "separator"?

Comment: There is something wrong with AFTER, it expands to nothing.

Comment: Have you looked into the Boost Preprocessor package? It works stand-alone without the Boost libraries just by including and collects many preprocessor tricks in one package.

Comment: @Sebastian Not lately as I cannot depend on boost in this use case. I was not aware though that it can be used stand-alone as well, so maybe it would have been an option. But it’s no longer a problem as HolyBackCat’s answer helped me solve the problem quite nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It becomes very easy if you do `#define SEPARATOR )(`:

```
#define SEPARATOR )(

#define BEFORE(...) BEFORE_1((__VA_ARGS__))
#define BEFORE_1(...) BEFORE_2 __VA_ARGS__ )
#define BEFORE_2(...) __VA_ARGS__ NULL(
#define NULL(...)

#define AFTER(...) AFTER_1((__VA_ARGS__))
#define AFTER_1(...) AFTER_2 __VA_ARGS__
#define AFTER_2(...) AFTER_3
#define AFTER_3(...) __VA_ARGS__

BEFORE(a, b, c, SEPARATOR, 1, 2, 3) // a,b,c,
AFTER(a, b, c, SEPARATOR, 1, 2, 3)  // ,1,2,3
```

This pastes the commas before and after `SEPARATOR` to the output, but dealing with that is left as an exercise to the reader (perhaps just change your syntax to remove the commas?).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. It indeed seems to make things a lot simpler. I’ll look into whether it will work for my actual use case!

Comment: Thanks again. This works indeed in my use case and I don’t have to use all the ugly eval and defer stuff!

Answer (score 1):

The following:

```
#define FIRST(a, ...) a
#define SECOND(a, b, ...) b

#define EMPTY()

#define EVAL(...) EVAL1024(__VA_ARGS__)
#define EVAL1024(...) EVAL512(EVAL512(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL512(...) EVAL256(EVAL256(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL256(...) EVAL128(EVAL128(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL128(...) EVAL64(EVAL64(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL64(...) EVAL32(EVAL32(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL32(...) EVAL16(EVAL16(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL16(...) EVAL8(EVAL8(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL8(...) EVAL4(EVAL4(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL4(...) EVAL2(EVAL2(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL2(...) EVAL1(EVAL1(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL1(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define DEFER2(m) m EMPTY EMPTY()()
#define DEFER3(m) m EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY()()()

#define IS_PROBE(...) SECOND(__VA_ARGS__, 0)
#define PROBE() ~, 1

#define CAT(a,b) a ## b

#define NOT(x) IS_PROBE(CAT(_NOT_, x))
#define _NOT_0 PROBE()

#define BOOL(x) NOT(NOT(x))

#define IF_ELSE(condition) _IF_ELSE(BOOL(condition))
#define _IF_ELSE(condition) CAT(_IF_, condition)

#define _IF_1(...) __VA_ARGS__ _IF_1_ELSE
#define _IF_0(...)             _IF_0_ELSE

#define _IF_1_ELSE(...)
#define _IF_0_ELSE(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define HAS_ARGS(...) BOOL(FIRST(_END_OF_ARGUMENTS_ __VA_ARGS__)())
#define _END_OF_ARGUMENTS_(...) 0

#define COMMAS_5    (,,,,,)
#define SEPARATOR   COMMAS_5

#define UNPACK(...)  __VA_ARGS__
#define IS_SEPARATOR_N(_7,_6,_5,_4,_3,_2,_1,N,...)  N()
#define IS_SEPARATOR(...)  IS_PROBE(IS_SEPARATOR_N(__VA_ARGS__,,PROBE,,,,,))

#define BEFORE_IMPL3(first, ...) IF_ELSE(IS_SEPARATOR(first))(/* do nothing */)(, first DEFER3(_BEFORE_IMPL2)()(__VA_ARGS__))
#define BEFORE_IMPL2(first, ...) IF_ELSE(HAS_ARGS(first))(BEFORE_IMPL3(first, __VA_ARGS__))()
#define _BEFORE_IMPL2() BEFORE_IMPL2
#define BEFORE_IMPL1(first, ...) IF_ELSE(IS_SEPARATOR(first))( /* do nothing */ )(first EVAL(BEFORE_IMPL2(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define BEFORE(first, ...)  IF_ELSE(HAS_ARGS(first))(BEFORE_IMPL1(first, __VA_ARGS__))()

#define AFTER_IMPL2(first, ...) IF_ELSE(IS_SEPARATOR(first))(__VA_ARGS__)(DEFER3(_AFTER_IMPL)()(__VA_ARGS__))
#define AFTER_IMPL(first, ...) IF_ELSE(HAS_ARGS(first))(AFTER_IMPL2(first, __VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)
#define _AFTER_IMPL() AFTER_IMPL
#define AFTER(...) EVAL(AFTER_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__))

#define M(...) BEFORE(__VA_ARGS__) && AFTER(__VA_ARGS__)

M(a, b, c, SEPARATOR, 1, 2, 3)
```

Expands to:

```
a , b , c && 1, 2, 3
```

You can increase `COMMAS_5` to, for example, `COMMAS_63` to protect against bigger number of arguments. Just a sequence of 5 commas is unique enough that the assumption is it will never come in one of the arguments.

I never liked EVAL DEFER tricks - the error message from compiler are completely unreadable. I prefer macro overload. Even when you have to spell out each case separately, it is very, very easy to generate and compiler messages are easier to read.

Such code would never fly my review. I see no value in "SEPARATOR" and in such code. The code is convoluted and hard to read and impossible to maintain. I would prefer programmers just write `BEFORE(a, b, c) && AFTER(1, 2, 3)` if they want to.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I’ll play with it and see if it will work for me.
I’m also not a big fan of this kind of coding. I’m currently exploring this solution and will try to compare it against a macro overload based one (if I manage to get that to work in this particular situation).

Regarding your last paragraph: I agree with the convolutedness, legibility, and maintainability concerns. If you knew the context, perhaps you’d see the value, but I can’t lay it out here. So please don’t judge too harshly.